# LINQ C# Join with Left-Join result

Tags: c#, linq, join, left-join

I'm trying to do a left-join with the result of another left-join but in some cases it returns me null reference error (obviously), is there any way to do this without using foreach after select?

```
var result = from f in foo
             from ex in exp.Where(w => w.id == f.idFoo).DefaultIfEmpty()
             from te in tes.Where(w => w.id == ex.anyID).DefaultIfEmpty()
select new
{
    var1 = f.something,
    ...
    var2 = te.anything
};
```

Comment: Is this linq to objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's happening because `DefaultIfEmpty` is returning a sequence with a single `null` element. Then you are trying to access properties on a `null` element.

Use [the overload of `DefaultIfEmpty` to return a non-null default value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb355419%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) (of the appropriate data type):

```
var result = from f in foo
             from ex in exp.Where(w => w.id == f.idFoo)
                           .DefaultIfEmpty(new Exp())
             from te in tes.Where(w => w.id == ex.anyID)
                           .DefaultIfEmpty(new Tes())
select new
{
    var1 = f.something,
    ...
    var2 = te.anything
};
```

That way you won't be trying to access properties on `null` elements.

**Edit based on comments**. In the query, one place that `null` elements arise is when a `Where` results in zero matches. For instance, in the third `from` the `ex` variable might be a sequence of one `null` element, and again in the `select` the `te` might also be such a sequence. In both cases, accessing a property will throw an exception.

Alternatively, you could do a null test *every time* you are going to access a property. That would become verbose fast.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
var2 = te != null ? te.anything : null
```

Comment: This won't work because he will still have the null reference exception in his `Where` clauses.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin No he wouldn't.  The point is that the sequence has some number of non-null elements, none pass the `Where`, and `DefaultOrEmpty` adds in a one item sequence with a `null` value.

Comment: @Servy What sequence has some number of non-null elements?

Comment: @Servy What do you mean by "non pass the `Where`"?

Comment: @ShaunLuttin `exp` and `te` both appear to be sequences of non-null elements.

Comment: @Servy When `DefaultOrEmpty` adds in a one item sequence with a `null` value, the subsequent `from` will try to access a property on a `null` value. Result: `tes.Where(w => w.id == ex.anyID)` will throw an exception.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin I mean that there are no items in those sequences for which the predicate in `Where` is true, resulting in `DefaultOrEmpty` adding a default value to the sequence.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin If there are any items in `tes`.

Comment: @Servy "...resulting in `DefaultOrEmpty` adding a default value to the sequence." That's what causes the null reference exception in the third `from` expression and in the `select` because the default is null.